# My nav menu disappears on desktop displays after clicking the hamburger menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried converting my mobile menu's JS code to jQuery, and it works! But it also created two slight problems. The jQuery code is not included in the code snippet since it won't replicate the issue. I'm using jQuery 3.4.1.

1. The nav menu on tablet/desktop displays disappears after clicking the mobile menu.
2. The hamburger menu is supposed to spin upon click, and now it doesn't move. *(I'm using third-party code for the hamburger animation effect, btw)*

Since I wasn't able to replicate the problem in the code snippet below, here it is in action ---> https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXqxm.jpg

Below is the code. It doesn't produce any console errors (when jQuery is included), so what do I need to fix?

```js
// Sticky Navbar & Back to Top ---------------------------------- /
// -------------------------------------------------------------- /
const navbar = document.getElementById('navbar');
const topArrow = document.getElementById('backToTop');

window.onscroll = function () {
    stickyNav() 
};
function stickyNav() {
    if (window.pageYOffset > 0) {
        navbar.classList.add('stickyNav');
        topArrow.classList.add('showBackToTop');
    
    } else {
        navbar.classList.remove('stickyNav');
        topArrow.classList.remove('showBackToTop');
    }
}
function topFunction() {
    document.body.scrollTop = 0;
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}


// Mobile Menu -------------------------------------------------- /
// -------------------------------------------------------------- /
// const hamburgerMenu = document.getElementsByClassName('hamburger')[0];
// const navbarMenu = document.getElementsByClassName('navMenu')[0];

// hamburgerMenu.addEventListener('click', () => {
//     hamburgerMenu.classList.toggle('is-active')
//     navbarMenu.classList.toggle('active')
// });

$('.hamburger').on('click', () => {
    $(this).toggle('is-active');
    $('.navMenu').toggle('active');
});
```

```css
/* Universal  ---------------------------------------------------------- */
/* --------------------------------------------------------------------- */
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

button {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 1em;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #00cee993;
    transition: .2s ease;
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

.moreQuestionsButton:hover {
    background-color: #00e90c93;
}

fieldset {
    border: none;
}

.card {
    border: 1px solid red;
    color: #222;
}

nav,
body,
button {
    font-family: 'Comfortaa', sans-serif;
}

#navbar {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

.stickyNav {
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
    box-shadow: #333 0 1px 10px;
    transition: .08s ease;
}

#backToTop {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    width: 50px;
    height: auto;
    right: 35px;
    bottom: 35px;
    z-index: 1000;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
}

#backToTop:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
    transition: ease .25s;
    background-color: #00cee9;
}

.showBackToTop {
    display: block !important;
}

.brandLogo {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    margin: 1rem;
}

.brandLogo a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
}

.brandLogo:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
    transition: ease .15s;
}

.navMenu {
    color: #333;
}

.navMenu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
}

.navMenu li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 5px;
    display: block;
}

.navMenu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
    padding: 1rem;
    display: block;
}

.navMenu li:hover {
    background-color: #00cee993;
    right: 200px;
    transition: ease-out .15s;
}

.hamburger {
    position: absolute;
    top: .15rem;
    right: .5rem;
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: .4rem;
}

.cardContainer {
    margin-top: 90px !important;
}

.centerText {
    text-align: center;
}

label, input {
    padding: 7px;
}

label {
    float: left;
}

input {
    float: right;
    width: 60%;
}



/* Mobile  ---------------------------------------------------------- */
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------ */
@media (min-width: 320px) {
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
        .hamburger {
            display: flex;
        }

        .navMenu {
            display: none;
            width: 100%;
        }

        #navbar {
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: flex-start;
        }

        .navMenu ul {
            display: block;
            flex-direction: column;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .navMenu li {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 1.2rem;
            margin: 5px 0;
        }

        .navMenu.active {
            display: flex;
        }

    }

    .cardContainer {
        width: 85%;
        margin: auto;
    }

    .cardContainer .card {
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 10px 30px;
        width: 100%;
    }


}

/* Tablet  ---------------------------------------------------------- */
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------ */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .hamburger {
        display: none !important;
    }

    .cardContainer {
        max-width: 70%;
    }

}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
    .cardContainer {
        max-width: 60%;
    }
}


/* -------------------------------------------------------------- /
// ---------------------- HAMBURGER CODE BELOW ------------------ /
// ------------------------------------------------------------- */


/*!
 * Hamburgers
 * @description Tasty CSS-animated hamburgers
 * @author Jonathan Suh @jonsuh
 * @site https://jonsuh.com/hamburgers
 * @link https://github.com/jonsuh/hamburgers
*/
.hamburger {
  padding: 15px 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition-property: opacity, filter;
  transition-duration: 0.15s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  font: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  text-transform: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: visible;
}

.hamburger:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.hamburger.is-active:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.hamburger.is-active .hamburger-inner,
.hamburger.is-active .hamburger-inner::before,
.hamburger.is-active .hamburger-inner::after {
  background-color: #333;
}

.hamburger-box {
  width: 35px;
  height: 24px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.hamburger-inner {
  display: block;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -2px;
}

.hamburger-inner,
.hamburger-inner::before,
.hamburger-inner::after {
  width: 30px;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-duration: 0.15s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
}

.hamburger-inner::before,
.hamburger-inner::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}

.hamburger-inner::before {
  top: -10px;
}

.hamburger-inner::after {
  bottom: -10px;
}


/* Spin */
.hamburger--spin .hamburger-inner {
  transition-duration: 0.22s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19); }
  .hamburger--spin .hamburger-inner::before {
    transition: top 0.1s 0.15s ease-in, opacity 0.1s ease-in; }
  .hamburger--spin .hamburger-inner::after {
    transition: bottom 0.1s 0.15s ease-in, transform 0.12s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19); }

.hamburger--spin.is-active .hamburger-inner {
  transform: rotate(225deg);
  transition-delay: 0.12s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1); }
  .hamburger--spin.is-active .hamburger-inner::before {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: top 0.1s ease-out, opacity 0.1s 0.12s ease-out; }
  .hamburger--spin.is-active .hamburger-inner::after {
    bottom: 0;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transition: bottom 0.1s ease-out, transform 0.12s 0.12s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1); }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>The Form</title>
    <meta name="description">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/stylesheet.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="javascript/jquery.js" defer></script>
    <script src="javascript/scripts.js" defer></script>
    
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <nav id="navbar">
            <div class="brandLogo"><a href="home.html">The Form</a></div>
            <button class="hamburger hamburger--spin" type="button">
                <span class="hamburger-box">
                    <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
                </span>
            </button>

            <div class="navMenu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="home.html">home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">about</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <main>
        <div>
            <img id="backToTop" src="icons/material design/svg/up-arrow-key.svg" onclick="topFunction()"
                title="Back to Top" />
        </div>

        <div class="cardContainer">
            <div class="card centerText">
                <div class="cardTitle">
                    <h1>Welcome to The Form!</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="cardContent">
                    <p>You fill it out and get a prize at the end!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div class="card centerText">
                <div class="cardTitle">
                    <h1>Start here</h1>
                    <hr>
                </div>
                <div class="cardContent">
                    <form action="/action_page.php">
                        <fieldset>
                            <label for="fname">First name:</label>
                            <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br><br>
                            <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
                            <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br><br>
                            <label for="email">Email:</label>
                            <input type="email" id="email" name="email"><br><br><br>
                            <label for="birthday">Birthday:</label>
                            <input type="date" id="birthday" name="birthday"><br><br><br>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>

                    <div>
                        <p>You can now submit the form and get a prize.</p>
                        <p><i>Or...</i></p>
                        <p>You can answer more questions and receive a bigger prize!</p>
                        <button class="moreQuestionsButton" type="submit" onclick="moreQuestions1()">Answer More Questions</button>
                        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        TEST
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        TEST
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
    </main>

















    <!-- Icons made by <a href="https://www.flaticon.com/authors/google" title="Google">Google</a> from <a
            href="https://www.flaticon.com/" title="Flaticon"> www.flaticon.com</a> -->
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code:- 
Use toggleClass instead of toggle

```
$('.hamburger').on('click', () => {
    $(this).toggleClass('is-active');
    $('.navMenu').toggleClass('active');
});
```

Comment: It works now, but the icon still doesn't spin like it's supposed to.

Here's what it's supposed to look like ---> https://imgur.com/a/1ovpcqF

Comment: Hi @juniordev123, Sorry for late reply. Use following code `$('.hamburger').on('click', (e) => {
    $(e.target).toggleClass('is-active');
    $('.navMenu').toggleClass('active');
}); ` it will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

this pretty simple you just need to add the following line of code in your style file.

When you click on hamburger icon an inline style applied on the menu, this style will override inline style on the big screen

https://www.screencast.com/t/EBoUMjwjsp

```
@media (min-width: 767px) {
 .navMenu {
   display: block !important;
 }
}
```